# How do I execute a Perl program on a remote machine?

Tags: linux, perl, tail

I wrote a Perl program to capture a live data stream from a `tail` command on a Linux machine using the following command in the console:

```
tail -f xyz.log | myperl.pl
```

It works fine. But now I have to execute this Perl program on a different machine because the log file is on that different machine. Can anyone tell me how I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could even say

```
ssh remotemachine bash -c "tail -f xyz.log | myperl.pl"
```

in order to run the script on the remote machine (if your script produces some output files and you want them on remote machine)

Answer (score 3):

You could say

```
ssh remotemachine tail -f xyz.log | myperl.pl
```

I suppose or maybe mount the remote log directories locally onto your administrative machine and do the processing there.